# OpenGL Library 3dXML

Tags: iphone

Looking for a starting point on importing and displaying a 3DXML model on the iPad.  Pretty sure that OpenGL is the way to go, but not seeing any ports that are able to read 3DXML models.

Does anyone have a starting point on this? (Have been looking at GLC_lib, but not seeing an objective C port)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if it's an app you want, I recommend 3DVia Mobile http://www.3dvia.com/products/3dvia-mobile/